# Comparing two objects of unknown type for sorting in .NET

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, compare

My task: I have an array of object values, and I need to sort them. In most cases values have the same primitive data type (Int32, DateTime, or String); however, in other cases we can have several types of data in this array (say integers and several strings). The type of values stored in the array is not known at compile time.

To solve the task, I wrote a custom comparer used in the corresponding `Array.Sort(Array array, IComparer comparer))' call. The method that compares two object values looks like this:

```cs
public static int CompareObjects(object valueX, object valueY)
{
    IComparable myValueX = valueX as IComparable;
    IComparable myValueY = valueY as IComparable;
    if (myValueX == null)
    {
        if (myValueY == null)
            return 0;
        return -1;
    }
    if (myValueY == null)
        return 1;

    if (!Type.Equals(myValueX, myValueY))
        return string.CompareOrdinal(myValueX.GetType().Name, myValueY.GetType().Name);

    return myValueX.CompareTo(myValueY);
}
```

My tests show that this method is a bottleneck, and I need to speed it up. Is there a faster way to compare two values of unknown types?

Comment: `Type.Equals` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to sort unlike types based on the ordinal ordering of the name strings?  That looks to me like a performance hog.  You may have better results sorting on the hash code for the unlike types and then only using the string when the hash codes are the same. @SLaks: I think `Type.Equals` does exactly what he wants here--for unlike types he wants them to have some kind of consistent sorting.

Comment: @SLaks, Why? I just need to separate two different data types, and do not compare them if they are different. Maybe, a better test expression for that 'if' would be `myValueX.GetType() != myValueY.GetType()`?

Comment: @James, do you mean `myValueX.GetHashCode().CompareTo(myValueY.GetHashCode())`? Why can it be better?

Comment: No. I'd do something like this: 

    if (!Type.Equals(myValueX, myValueY))
            {
                int ret = myValueX.GetType().GetHashCode().CompareTo(myValueY.GetType().GetHashCode());
                if (ret != 0) return ret;
                return string.CompareOrdinal(myValueX.GetType().Name, myValueY.GetType().Name);
            }
This compares the hashcodes for the types first, which is much faster than comparing the names of the types and only resorts to comparing the names in the rare case when the hashcodes are the same.

Comment: @itsme86, I need to return an integer value used for the IComparer implementation.

Comment: And which part specifically is slow? Try running profiler to find out.

Comment: @James: There is no `Type.Equals()`.  That's actually `object.Equals()`.

Comment: @SLaks: The reference source disagrees with you: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,451a7917376bcfb4

Comment: @SLaks: Type.Equals does exist, but I do see your point.  It doesn't compare the types of the objects being passed in.  It should be Type.Equals (myValueX.GetType(), myValueY.GetType()).

Comment: @James: No; that's an instance method.

Comment: @SLaks: Quite right.  My bad!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need objects sorted primarily by their type name (a huge part of the cost of your function), this fixes the type comparison bug and in a simple test case with unlike types which both implement `IComparable`, provides a 25% measured performance boost as well (over the same function without the `Type.GetHashCode()` optimization):

```
    public static int CompareObjects(object valueX, object valueY)
    {
        IComparable myValueX = valueX as IComparable;
        IComparable myValueY = valueY as IComparable;
        if (myValueX == null)
        {
            if (myValueY == null)
                return 0;
            return -1;
        }
        if (myValueY == null)
            return 1;
        Type typeX = valueX.GetType();
        Type typeY = valueY.GetType();
        if (!typeX.Equals(typeY))
        {
            int ret = typeX.GetHashCode().CompareTo(typeY.GetHashCode());
            if (ret != 0) return ret;
            return string.CompareOrdinal(typeX.Name, typeY.Name);
        }

        return myValueX.CompareTo(myValueY);
    }
```

Note that there are issues with this implementation too, as it doesn't properly compare objects that don't inherit from IComparable.  That may or may not be an issue for you.

For the doubters, here is a simple program that proves comparing GetHashCode() on the Types is a performance improvement:

```
class Program
{
    class Comparable1 : IComparable<Comparable1>, IComparable
    {
        private int _value;
        public Comparable1()
        {
            _value = new Random().Next();
        }
        public int CompareTo(Comparable1 other)
        {
            return _value.CompareTo(other._value);
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            return CompareTo(obj as Comparable1);
        }
    }
    class Comparable2 : IComparable<Comparable2>, IComparable
    {
        private int _value;
        public Comparable2()
        {
            _value = new Random().Next();
        }
        public int CompareTo(Comparable2 other)
        {
            return _value.CompareTo(other._value);
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            return CompareTo(obj as Comparable2);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Comparable1 x = new Comparable1();
        Comparable2 y = new Comparable2();
        Stopwatch version1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int round = 0; round < 10000000; ++round)
        {
            CompareObjects1(x, y);
        }
        version1.Stop();
        Stopwatch version2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int round = 0; round < 10000000; ++round)
        {
            CompareObjects2(x, y);
        }
        version2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time1=" + version1.ElapsedTicks.ToString() + ", Time2=" + version2.ElapsedTicks.ToString());
    }
    public static int CompareObjects1(object valueX, object valueY)
    {
        IComparable myValueX = valueX as IComparable;
        IComparable myValueY = valueY as IComparable;
        if (myValueX == null)
        {
            if (myValueY == null)
                return 0;
            return -1;
        }
        if (myValueY == null)
            return 1;
        Type typeX = valueX.GetType();
        Type typeY = valueY.GetType();
        if (!typeX.Equals(typeY))
        {
            return string.CompareOrdinal(typeX.Name, typeY.Name);
        }

        return myValueX.CompareTo(myValueY);
    }
    public static int CompareObjects2(object valueX, object valueY)
    {
        IComparable myValueX = valueX as IComparable;
        IComparable myValueY = valueY as IComparable;
        if (myValueX == null)
        {
            if (myValueY == null)
                return 0;
            return -1;
        }
        if (myValueY == null)
            return 1;
        Type typeX = valueX.GetType();
        Type typeY = valueY.GetType();
        if (!typeX.Equals(typeY))
        {
            int ret = typeX.GetHashCode().CompareTo(typeY.GetHashCode());
            if (ret != 0) return ret;
            return string.CompareOrdinal(typeX.Name, typeY.Name);
        }

        return myValueX.CompareTo(myValueY);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix [the OP's bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319917/comparing-two-objects-of-unknown-type-for-sorting-in-net#comment43099119_27319917).  Also, it would only ever slow down the code.  Hash codes are useful when they allow you to easily "compare" an object against a large number of other objects through the hash.  When there is only ever one object to compare it with, it's not going to be a net win.

Comment: I've fixed the bug now.  There is a significant (25%) performance improvement (measured) because `GetHashCode()` is much, much faster than a string compare of the type names.  The one compares the pointers, the other has to compare variable length `Int16` sequences.

Comment: No, it's really not.  They're going to be *very* comparable.  There's actually a very strong possibility that it'll be *slower*.  The use of hashes is useful in the context of a hash based table, in which using a hash to find the corresponding hash bucket allows one object to be conceptually compared to N objects for the same amount of effort it would take to compare them to a fixed number of items.  When you have a large collection that is *great* and can have *huge* performance improvements, but *it requires having a large number of values to compare* to be a net win.  You have just 2.

Comment: The hash code for a string is *not* dependent on its pointer.  Equal strings need to have an equal hash, and you can have multiple string instances (each with their own reference) with a logically equal value.  The hash has to be based on the actual characters in the string.

Comment: Let me quote from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx:
The GetHashCode method can be overridden by a derived type. If GetHashCode is not overridden, hash codes for reference types are computed by calling the Object.GetHashCode method of the base class, which computes a hash code based on an object's reference.

Comment: I'm not comparing the hash codes of the strings.  I'm comparing hash codes of the `Type`s--huge difference.

Comment: Also, the string comparison is going to first check if the string references are the same, and if so, it'll short circuit by returning 0.

Comment: You can only omit the string test if the objects are equal, not when they're different.  Your code doesn't return the correct result.  Once you fix that you'll see it running *slower* with your "optimization" for the test you have.

Comment: Can you give me an example of when it doesn't return the correct result?

Comment: The fact that one object's type's hash code is greater than the other doesn't mean that the type's name is greater than the other type's name.  If the hashes are equal it only means that the types *might* be equal.  If they're different it only tells you that the objects are different, not which is greater than the other.  Of course, you already know that they're not equal because you've already done the `Equals` check.  Just look at the sorted results; it doesn't necessarily sort all of the objects alphabetically by their type name.

Comment: Is there some requirement I didn't see that unlike objects need to be sorted by their type name string?  I did ask about that in the comments above.

Comment: And you didn't get an answer, just another question.

Comment: So, absent an answer from the OP, I should assume that he wants it to work exactly the same as before, only faster, even though it doesn't work to begin with?!

Comment: I didn't disappear. And I find James' approach magnificent. However, the question I had posed led me to another thinking: how to process the situation when we have values of different types in the array to sort? We just need a result that can have a sense, not more. And we need to gain it the fastest way. From this point of view, I would even avoid calling `Type.GetHashCode` and `Type.Name` and simply replace all this block with the `Type.GetTypeCode` comparison. Let me do some tests before I mark this answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Comparing type hash codes leads to unpredictable sort results: if we have strings and integers in the same array, sometimes strings are placed before integers, in other cases integers are followed by strings.

Comment: @TecMan: If the sort needs to be consistent across runs, then the use of GetHashCode is definitely out, even for strings.  Assuming the sorting happens a lot, and you know all the types that are going to be involved ahead of time, you could create a global dictionary with a sort code (based on the type name string compares) and use that to sort unlike types.  That would allow for consistent sorting and still be far faster than comparing strings.  You might even be able to build it dynamically using a ConditionalWeakTable.  There is some overhead to that, but if you're doing a lot of sorting...